# Hook into every request in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, hook

Unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902231/laravel-hook-into-eloquent-pre-and-post-save-for-every-model), I would like to hook a method into every request made to my web application. How would I do this?

**Put in another way**
There are some functionalities that I would want to be executed on whenever anybody checks on my web application. Most likely, I think I would put it in a method and call this method somewhere within Laravel. I don't want to write a daemon. I don't know how to do this. Please, help out. Drop a comment if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) is specifically designed to do this sort of thing. Define a middleware, then apply it globally, or to specific routes.

Comment: Thank you, although I had to do some more reading and experimentation with the docs...

Comment: Moreover, you will have specify what route/controller the **middleware** should work on, but **service provider** runs throughout the whole application